# How to save the file with different name and not overwriting existing one

Tags: python, file, plot

I need to run a python script repeatedly over different data set. This python script test.py processes the data set, plot and save the result using the command.

```
plt.savefig('result.png')
```

How can I ensure that when the same `test.py` scripts runs on another data set.. the new `result.png` doesn't overwrite my previous result? Basically before executing `plt.savefig('result.png')`, I need to check if result.png already exist and if does then rename the result to any other name like

```
result1.png
result2.png
```

Otherwise, in the next post processing the file is overwritten.

Comment: You can use `os.path.exists` to check whether the file already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import time
if os.path.exists('result.png'):
    plt.savefig('result_{}.png'.format(int(time.time())))
else:
    plt.savefig('result.png')
```

Comment: Note that in its current form this will fail in case two results are created within the same second. Probably does not matter, just wanted to point out.

Comment: Man, the time taken in plotting the matplotlib plot is more than a second in normal scenarios.

Comment: @ManguSinghRajpurohit: I like how you used time but [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) is right if some uses threading to save multiple images then this can be a problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `os.path.exists` to check whether the file already exists, and if so, append a number. Repeat with the new file name until you find one that does not yet exist.

```
def unique_file(basename, ext):
    actualname = "%s.%s" % (basename, ext)
    c = itertools.count()
    while os.path.exists(actualname):
        actualname = "%s (%d).%s" % (basename, next(c), ext)
    return actualname
```

Example-usage:

```
for i in range(5):
    with open(unique_file("foo", "txt"), "w") as f:
        f.write(str(i))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tempfile.mkstemp` available in the standard library

```
import tempfile
fi, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix='result_', suffix='.png')
```

Note: `fi` is an integer. In case you need a file object do

```
f = os.fdopen(fi, "w")
```

whereas `filename` includes the absolute pathname of the created file, e.g.

```
'/tmp/result_d_3787js.png'
```

Another solution is to use UUIDs, e.g.

```
import uuid
filename = 'result_'+str(uuid.uuid4())+'.png'
```

which produces something like

```
result_cf29d123-271e-4899-b2f6-d172f157af65.png
```

Please see the official docs for further info and parameters
on [mkstemp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) and [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html?highlight=uuid#module-uuid)